# An array of id to filter an Array via NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

The following predicate works if I only pass a single `itemId` but I wonder what if I have multiple `itemId` s, how could I able to make it work ?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", kItemId, itemId];
NSArray *filteredArray = [restaurantData.itemArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `IN` query:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"(%K IN %@)", kItemId, yourArrayOfItemId];
```